# Android wear creating Emulator ERROR "Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module"

Tags: android

I recently update my Studio to version- 2.0 for Win7  and now i am not able to create  wear AVD, I am getting error

"Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module"

I check my BIOS setup and VT-x is enabled.

Please see below screenshot

[image]

Comment: was this working before updating studio?

Comment: yes it was working before updating studio

Answer (score 2):

Before need to install `KVM` or (`Kernel-based Virtual Machine`) on your machine

refer this link to install kvm http://www.howtogeek.com/117635/how-to-install-kvm-and-create-virtual-machines-on-ubuntu/

I hope it will help you.